# C# StackOverflowException when use getter

Tags: c#, getter

I have getter which changes the first letter of a string to capital. But I get StackOverflowException.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Human
        {     
            public String Name
            {
                get
                {

                    char[] letters = Name.ToCharArray();
                    // upper case the first char
                    letters[0] = char.ToUpper(letters[0]);
                    // return the array made of the new char array
                    return new String(letters);
                    //return Name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", Name.Skip(1));
                }
                set
                {
                
                }
            }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Dear lord, where do I begin?

Comment: Give the boy a chance, he might be a beginner struggling with his first lines of code.

Comment: First, your example code won't compile. 2 return statements and an open parenthesis. Second, your getter is referencing itself recursively. You need to set up a private string _Name and do your calculations on it.

Comment: Yes is my first line of code in C#. Anyway CLAPTRAP revolution!:P

Answer (score 6):

This line `char[] letters = Name.ToCharArray();` calls recursively the property `public String Name`

Answer (score 4):

Your property `Name` is calling itself in line `char[] letters = Name.ToCharArray();`. You will have to use a field instead of the property:

```
class Human
{     
    private string _name;

    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name == null)
                return null;
            if (_name.Length <= 1)
                return _name.ToUpper() + _name.Substring(1);
            return _name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + _name.Substring(1);
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I also took the freedom to try to make your function work with the upper casing. Or in my opinion even better:

```
class Human
{     
    private string _name = "";

    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
                _name = value;
            else  
                _name = value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + _value.Substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move your _name field out of the property and I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @MadHenchbot: Hahaha, that is a nice and stupid mistake! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are accesing the getter inside the getter.

You should create a backing variable and access that variable instead of the Name:

```
class Human
    {     
    private string _name = string.Empty;    
    public String Name
        {
            get
            {

                char[] letters = _name.ToCharArray();  // use the backing variable instead of Name
                // upper case the first char
                letters[0] = char.ToUpper(letters[0]);
                // return the array made of the new char array
                return new String(letters);
                //return Name.First().ToString().ToUpper() + String.Join("", Name.Skip(1));

                return new String(;// ToUpperFirstLetter(this.Imie);
            }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char[] letters = Name.ToCharArray();
```

When you try to read something from `Name`, you're using the getter. Thus you've caused an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working Name method, which makes the first letter of the sentence uppercase, when you get the value.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
        {
            return _name;
        }
        var charArray = _name.ToCharArray();
        charArray[0] = char.ToUpper(charArray[0]);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```